# Finding power absorbed by resistor

Tags: power

### Data:

[image]
\$ J = 1 A\$
\$ R = 2Ω\$
\$ R_{1} = 4Ω\$
\$ R_{2} = 6Ω\$
\$ k = 16 \$ - times

### Calculations:

\$ J' = kJ = 16 *1A = 16A\$

\$ J = I_{1}+I_{2}\$

\$ J \frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}} = I_{2}R_{2}\$

\$ I_{2}= J \frac{R_{1}R_{2}}{(R_{1}+R_{2})R_{2}}\$

\$ I_{2}= J \frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}\$

\$P_{2} = I_{2}^{2}R_{2} = (J \frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})^{2}R_{2} \$

\$P'_{2} = (J' \frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})^{2}R_{2} \$

\$P'_{2} - P_{2} = (J' \frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})^{2}R_{2} - (J \frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})^{2}R_{2} = (J'^{2} - J^{2})(\frac{R_{1}}{R_{1}+R_{2}})^{2}R_{2}\$

Not sure how to continue, but anyone sees some obvious mistakes that I've made so far? Thanks

Comment: Are you supposed to find the increment in watts, or the increment as a ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this way too complicated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2OQ9o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. First step ...*

Combine R1 and R2. Now you can work out the voltage across 'R5'. Once you have that you can work out the power in R2 using the formula that relates P, V and R. Do you know it?

Note that the question as written can be solved in one step. Since \$ P = I^2R \$ then if the current goes up by a factor of 16 what happens the power? I would then say that the increment in power is that number minus 1.

Comment: Can I calculate the power in R2 using this formula? \$ P = \frac{U_{R_{5}}^{2}}{R_{5}} \$?

Comment: Use `\$` for inline MathJAX. `\$ \frac {top}{bottom} \$` gives \$ \frac {top}{bottom} \$. You have a couple of minutes before the comment is locked. Anyway, I think you've got it!

Comment: Putting aside my question about power, is the correct answer simply '15'? :o

And about the Power in \$R_{2}\$. Should I divide the \$U_{R_{5}}^{2}\$ by \$R_{5}\$ or by \$R_2\$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is going to get to confusing. Edit your question add an "Update" section to the bottom and draw the schematic / schematics using the CircuitLab button and show your calculations underneath. It's way past bedtime in Ireland. Good night. Oh - please un-accept the answer for a day or two to encourage other answers which may give you better insights to solving this problem than I have.

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the power delivered to resistor \$R_2\$, you may not regard the resistor $R$ because the current reaching the node which gathers \$R_2\$ and \$R_1\$ is always J. So you can relate the power by using the current divider relationship, which is :

\$I_2= J \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}\$ and later \$P_2 = {(I_2)}^2 R_2\$

Done that, \$I_2'=16J \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}\$. Behold that \$I_2'= 16I_2\$ and once more \$P_2'=256(I_2)^2R_2\$.

Now you can find the increment in power( percentage maybe? Specify that please) by simply divinding one by the other, thus:

\$ \frac{P_2'}{P_2} = 256 \$. The increment is 256 times the initial power, or \$25500\%\$

Comment: On EE.SE inline MathJAX uses `\$` open and closing tags.

Comment: @Transistor I actually tried to do that, but it made no change in my text. I tried that into that division P'2 / P2

Comment: I've fixed it for you using `\$` as explained.